# Parceljs not bundling properly for prod?

Tags: javascript, parceljs

i'm testing parceljs, and works fine for development. i have a normal css to just change background colors, and a very simple js file just to see if it's working.

**css**

```
body {
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**js**

```
document.getElementById('app').textContent = 'hey'
```

so all of that are working in dev mode. but i tried live server on the /dist/index.html, and all i see is the bare html. no styling, and the script doesn't render. I also tried the 'parcel build' command. and the same thing. What do I need to do?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "parceltest1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel ./src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
  }
}
```

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/src.e31bb0bc.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding "--public-url ./" to your parcel command. 
More on this here: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1865

Comment: This is the dumbest thing that that's not the default... The entire app has broken links if you use... folders... in your app? This is the "super simple, zero config" bundler? Horrible default behavior in my (unqualified) opinion. +1 for the answer, worked for me